# JDBC Metada retrieve Constraint information

Tags: oracle, jdbc, metadata

I need information about table and column name from the name of the constraint.

exists someone similar to connection.getMetadata().getX to retrieve the constraint information?

my test case is in Oracle Database, but my best solution I just want to solve with jdbc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are talking about foreign key and primary key constraints. The `DatabaseMetaData` does provide methods for retrieving this information: you can use [`getImportedKeys(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getImportedKeys%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`getCrossReference(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getCrossReference%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for foreign keys, and [`getPrimaryKeys(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getPrimaryKeys%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`getExportedKeys(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getExportedKeys%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)  for primary keys.

Just be careful how you use them: `getCrossReference(..)` and `getExportedKeys` are a bit counter-intuitive in my opinion.

If you also need unique constraints, then you should be able to use [`getIndexInfo(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getIndexInfo%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) with passing `true` for the parameter `unique`.

Answer (score 6):

You can get defined constraints information from [`USER_CONSTRAINTS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_2510.htm) and [`ALL_CONSTRAINTS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1037.htm#i1576022) table.
You need to pass required where clause fields.

**Example** :

```
select 
    CONSTRAINT_NAME,
    CONSTRAINT_TYPE,
    TABLE_NAME,
    ...
from
    USER_CONSTRAINTS
where
    CONSTRAINT_NAME like concat(?, '%');
```