# How to check if a constraint exists in a Java class?

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing

I have written a test class for an another class which used Hibernate Constraints. In the test class, I verify if the constraint is violated or not.

But what if while refactoring the original class the programmer forgot to annotate the class with constraints. How to test if a constraint exists or not.

---

To clarify, I have a class defined as such -

```
Class User {
    @Email
    String email;

    @NumberFormat
    @Length(min = 8, max = 16)
    String phoneNumber;

    /*Getters and Setters Omitted*/
}
```

Checking for property `String email;` to have the constraint `@Email`

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this with an ORM, but you could do it with plain old JDBC. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494549/jdbc-metada-retrieve-constraint-information

Comment: I am not accessing any external data. These constraints are Annotations and validators in hibernate

Comment: Oh I see, you're checking the entity to make sure that a Hibernate constraint still exists.

Comment: Yes. I have written code for constraint violations. But what if while refactoring, the programmer forgets to update constraints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you try to do is rather cumbersome and it is not really a unit test as 
a unit test should valid a specific behavior of a component.
Here, you want to validate the structure of the class.

If you are afraid that someone removes the validator annotation, I think that you should modify your unit test to check that if the email is not provided as expected for an entity user you are validating, the validation provides
a `ConstraintViolation` instance with the good message/path.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this using reflection. There's a nice tutorial here:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/annotations.html

Basically it would work something like this:

```
Class myEntity = MyEntity.class;
Field someField = myEntity.getField("someField");
Annotation[] annotations = someField.getAnnotations();

for(Annotation annotation : annotations){
    if(annotation instanceof Length){
        Length length = (Length) annotation;
        System.out.println("value: " + length.value());
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should give you enough to go on.

Comment: I have to ask. Are there any test frameworks which do this? Such as assertThat(MyEntity.class).hasField(myEntity.getField("someField")).hasAnnotation("Length");

Comment: I'm not sure, I've never tried to do it before. I did some annotation processing recently though so that came to mind.